# Fill the remainder of a CGContext, keeping one rectangle transparent

Tags: ios, cgcontext

I want to fill the remaining part of a CGCntext after drawing a rect? How can I do that? Thank you!

---

But the thing is, I set the blend mode of the cgcontext kCGBlendModeClear. I want to make the little rect in the context to transparent. If a draw the background first, can I still see the image in the rect?

Comment: I don't know much about CGContext, but can you set the background, or can you draw the whole space with a rectangle before drawing the smaller one?

Comment: Yes, you can very easily do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to fill the context (whose frame is `bigRect`), except for a rectangle inside it (whose frame is `smallRect`):

```
CGContextBeginPath(context);
CGContextAddRect(context, bigRect);
CGContextAddRect(context, smallRect);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color);
CGContextEOFillPath(context, bigRect);
```

Comment: CGContextEOFillPath takes only one parameter: CGContextEOFillPath(context);

Answer (score 0):

Do the background first...

```
    CGRect bounds = [self bounds];
    [[UIColor blackColor] set];
    UIBezierPath* backgroundPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:bounds];
    [backgroundPath fill];

    CGRect innerRect = CGRectMake(self.bounds-10, 
                                  self.bounds-10, 
                                  self.bounds.width-20
                                  self.bounds.height-20);
    [[UIColor redColor] set];
    UIBezierPath* foregroundPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:innerRect];
    [foregroundPath fill];
```

Comment: But the thing is, I set the blend mode of the cgcontext kCGBlendModeClear. I want to make the little rect in the context to transparent. If a draw the background first, can I still see the image in the rect?

Comment: I want to make the remainding part transparent.

Comment: If I don't know the rect is filled with red. An image is drawn on the context. Can I still get the little rect or a little circle of the iamge?

Comment: Perhaps you should post some code and/ or a picture of the effect you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Draw your background and then use `CGContextClearRect` to clear the area you want to be transparent.

arbitrary shape:

```
// do your foreground drawing

CGPathRef arbitraryShape; // asign your arbitrary shape
CGContextBeginPath(ctx);
CGContextAddRect(ctx, bounds); // rect in full size of the context
CGContextAddPath(ctx, arbitraryShape); // set the area you dont want to be drawn on
CGContextClip(ctx);

// do your background drawing
```

Comment: If it is not a rect? It may be an arbitrary shape. Does a path work?